# qunit reports results before execution is finished

Tags: qunit

I'm still new to QUnit. There's the snippet

```
<body>
  <div id=qunit></div>
  <div id=qunit-fixture>
  ..
  <a title=something href=#>foo</a>
  </div>
```

and the corresponding test case contains

```
$( 'a').each( function() { 
  console.debug( this);
  // do something
} );
```

However, QUnit inserts the results in #qunit, including some hyperlinks, which in turn appear in the test case (inside the each). Obviously, content inserted by QUnit should be outside the test's scope. Any suggestion for how to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QUnit deals with this by having your place the HTML your test needs inside the `qunit-fixture` element, so instead of:

`$('a').each(function() { ... });`

you would do:

`$('#qunit-fixture a').each(function() { ... });`

in your test case.

This lets you isolate your tests without depending on other page contents. The QUnit documentation provides [more information about this](http://qunitjs.com/cookbook/#keeping-tests-atomic) methodology.